# Как из строки сгенерировать png?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, png

Есть класс, который генерирует `svg` (строка). Дальше эту строку я вставляю в `html`. Потом генерирую `png`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      expand: false,
      svg: '',
      result: [],
      svgs: [
        '<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="-30 -40 336.6666666666667 283.3333333333333" id="maker-svg" style="padding : 10px; display: none;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"><g id="svgGroup" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="13.333333333333334" stroke="#03a9f4" stroke-width="0.5mm" fill="rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.1)" style="stroke:#03a9f4;stroke-width:0.5mm;fill:rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.1)"><path d="M 23.333 223.333 L 73.333 23.333 L 173.333 23.333 L 223.333 223.333 L 23.333 223.333 Z" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><path d="M 173.333 23.333 L 173.333 13.333 L 223.333 13.333 L 223.333 223.333 L 223.333 233.333 L 23.333 233.333 L 23.333 223.333 L 23.333 13.333 L 73.333 13.333 L 73.333 23.333 L 13.333 23.333 L 13.333 223.333 L 23.333 223.333 L 23.333 13.333" id="gray" stroke="gray" style="stroke:gray" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><g id="captions"><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(0,123.333,246.667)" x="123.333" y="246.667">L: 200</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(0,198.333,0)" x="198.333" y="0">L1: 50</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(0,48.333,0)" x="48.333" y="0">L2: 50</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(270,0,123.333)" x="0" y="123.333">H: 200</text></g></g></svg>',
        '<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="-72.35 -10 694.6166666666667 1495.6166666666666" id="maker-svg" style="padding : 10px;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"><g id="svgGroup" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="83.13333333333333" stroke="#03a9f4" stroke-width="0.5mm" fill="rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.1)" style="stroke:#03a9f4;stroke-width:0.5mm;fill:rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.1)"><path d="M 145.483 1247 L 591.483 1247 L 591.483 0 L 145.483 0 L 145.483 1247 Z" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><path d="M 145.483 0 L 83.133 0 L 83.133 1247 L 145.483 1247 L 145.483 1309.35 L 591.483 1309.35 L 591.483 1247" id="gray" stroke="gray" style="stroke:gray" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><g id="captions"><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(0,368.483,1392.483)" x="368.483" y="1392.483">L: 446</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(270,0,623.5)" x="0" y="623.5">H: 1247</text></g></g></svg>',
                '<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="-30 -40 336.6666666666667 283.3333333333333" id="maker-svg" style="padding : 10px; display: none;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"><g id="svgGroup" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="13.333333333333334" stroke="#03a9f4" stroke-width="0.5mm" fill="rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.1)" style="stroke:#03a9f4;stroke-width:0.5mm;fill:rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.1)"><path d="M 23.333 223.333 L 73.333 23.333 L 173.333 23.333 L 223.333 223.333 L 23.333 223.333 Z" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><path d="M 173.333 23.333 L 173.333 13.333 L 223.333 13.333 L 223.333 223.333 L 223.333 233.333 L 23.333 233.333 L 23.333 223.333 L 23.333 13.333 L 73.333 13.333 L 73.333 23.333 L 13.333 23.333 L 13.333 223.333 L 23.333 223.333 L 23.333 13.333" id="gray" stroke="gray" style="stroke:gray" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><g id="captions"><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(0,123.333,246.667)" x="123.333" y="246.667">L: 200</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(0,198.333,0)" x="198.333" y="0">L1: 50</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(0,48.333,0)" x="48.333" y="0">L2: 50</text><text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" transform="rotate(270,0,123.333)" x="0" y="123.333">H: 200</text></g></g></svg>',
      ],
    }
  },

  methods: {
    generate() {
      
      for (let i = 0; i < this.svgs.length; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.svg = this.svgs[i];
        const doctype = '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>';
        const source = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(d3.select('#svg-container svg').node());
        const blob = new Blob([doctype + source], {
          type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'
        });
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const img = d3.select(document.createElement('div')).append('img')
          .attr('width', 400)
          .attr('height', 400)
          .node();

        img.onload = () => {
          // Now that the image has loaded, put the image into a canvas element.
          var canvas = d3.select(document.createElement('div')).append('canvas').node();
          canvas.width = 400;
          canvas.height = 400;
          var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
          var canvasUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
          
          console.log(canvasUrl);
          
          this.result.push(canvasUrl);
        }
        img.src = url;
        }, 0);
      }
      
      console.log(this.result);
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <v-app>
      <v-content>
        <v-btn
          @click="generate"
        >
          Generate PNG
        </v-btn>
        <div id="svg-container" v-html="svg">
          
        </div>
      </v-content>
    </v-app>
  </template>
</div>
```

Результат без цикла:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никак не получается сгенерировать в цикле. Подскажите, может необходим другой метод для генерации изображения из `svg` в `png`?

Comment: что из этого не работает?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ на событие  `img.onload` навешивается функция. Но событие не успевает наступить а цикл отработал. А если  `() => {...}` сразу вызывать, то `png` пустая. Может есть вариант без события создавать?

Comment: в приведенном примере не вижу цикла

Comment: @StrangerintheQ обновил.

Comment: а где элементу img, для которого onload выставляется присваивается `src`?

Comment: что значит _Никак не получается сгенерировать в цикле_? А без цикла получается?

Comment: @Grundy да, получается.

Comment: что в цикле происходит? Для чего конкретно он нужен?

Comment: @Grundy есть массив с позициями и по нажатию на кнопку необходимо сгенерировать к каждой позиции из `svg` в `png` которая потом пойдёт в `pdf`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99437/discussion-between-grundy-and-doox911).